# SQL join, group and concat to get matching data and also view (null)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble getting the desired output.

This is the SQLfiddle I put together of my scenario:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9beffe/111

The output I get is as seen in the SQLfiddle.

The desired output should be:

```
user_name   participants_project    participants_user
Username 1  1                       1
Username 2  1                       (null)
Username 3  1                       3
Username 4  1                       (null)
```

So I want it to always show all 4 users, that is matching the project specified, and the participants_user should be defined if the user/project exists in the participants db and if not defined it should get the user info with **null** data for project, participants tables columns.

How do I achieve it?

Comment: Hi, I tried to solve issue you are facing but, seems to me I'm missing something, I need to understand schema you have for your tables, what I got is `users` table and `projects` table have `M:M` relationship through `participants` table, is that correct? and for `participants_user`, `participants_project` are not clear for me can you explain them and what the corresponding columns they are related to in the other tables?

Comment: @mamounothman Thanks for trying to help me out. There's 3 tables in total, `users`, `projects` and `participants`. The `users`-table basically contain all user details on the site. And the `projects`-table contain all the project data. What the `participants`-table is supposed to do is to store what user that are connected to each project as a participant. The function this is going to be used to is a drop-down menu on each project row where you can see a list of all users as a checkbox, where you can check/uncheck them as a partcipant.

Comment: What about the participants_user, participants_project fields, what role they play in the tables?

Comment: @mamounothman Oh sorry, what the participants_user field is ment to do is store what user_id that is an participant from `users`, and the participants_project field is to store what project_id from the `projects` the participant should be connected to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is below -

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.user_name, pp.participants_project, pp.participants_user
FROM `users` u
LEFT JOIN `participants` pp ON u.user_id = pp.participants_user
                            AND pp.participants_project = 1
ORDER BY u.user_name
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9beffe/193) is the fiddle.

With the fact that `Username 2` and `Username 4` is not having any project, So column `participants_project` would also have null values.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is this:

```
SELECT `users`.`user_name`, GROUP_CONCAT(`participants_project`), `participants_user` from `users` 
LEFT JOIN `participants` on users.user_id = `participants`.`participants_user` 
LEFT JOIN `projects` on `participants`.`participants_project` =`projects`.`project_id`
GROUP BY `users`.`user_id`
```

In the SQL code snippet, I added JOIN table for the `users` table and went through the `participants` table this will always list the users whether they have project or not, and in case you want to omit the users if they are not participating in a project just change 'LEFT JOIN' to be 'RIGHT JOIN' like this:

```
SELECT `users`.`user_name`, GROUP_CONCAT(`participants_project`), `participants_user` from `users`
LEFT JOIN `participants` on users.user_id = `participants`.`participants_user` 
LEFT JOIN `projects` on `participants`.`participants_project` =`projects`.`project_id` GROUP BY `users`.`user_id`
```

I suggest that you include Primary key and foreign key in the schema as it speeds up the query execution time and also you will have more consistent data persistence in you database tables.